# How map only left value from scala Either?

Tags: scala, either

Consider a code:

```
val some: OneCaseClass Either TwoCaseClass = ???
val r = some.left.map(_.toString)
```

Why is r `Serializable with Product with Either[String, TwoCaseClass]` type instead of `Either[String, TwoCaseClass]`?

How to map only left value?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Because that *is* the return type of [`LeftProjection.map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.Either$$LeftProjection@map[X](f:A=%3EX):ProductwithSerializablewithscala.util.Either[X,B]).

```
map[X](f: (A) ⇒ X): Product with Serializable with Either[X, B]
```

But this is not a problem. You can use type ascription if you wish:

```
val r: Either[String, TwoCaseClass] = some.left.map(_.toString)
```

Take a look at the examples on the [`Either` docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.util.Either):

```
val l: Either[String, Int] = Left("flower")
val r: Either[String, Int] = Right(12)
l.left.map(_.size): Either[Int, Int] // Left(6)
r.left.map(_.size): Either[Int, Int] // Right(12)
l.right.map(_.toDouble): Either[String, Double] // Left("flower")
r.right.map(_.toDouble): Either[String, Double] // Right(12.0)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that now (Scala 2.12) Either is right-biased. You don't have to explicitly do a right projection any more to map the value. So: r.map(_.toDouble) is equivalent to r.right.map(_.toDouble)